# python set comprehension for 2.6

Tags: python, set, set-comprehension

I was trying set comprehension for 2.6, and came across the following two ways. I thought the first method would be faster than the second, `timeit` suggested otherwise. Why is the second method faster even though the second method has got an extra list instantiation followed by a set instantiation?

Method 1:

```
In [16]: %timeit set(node[0] for node in pwnodes if node[1].get('pm'))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 568 ns per loop
```

Method 2:

```
In [17]: %timeit set([node[0] for node in pwnodes if node[1].get('pm')]) 
1000000 loops, best of 3: 469 ns per loop
```

where `pwnodes = [('e1', dict(pm=1, wired=1)), ('e2', dict(pm=1, wired=1))]`.

Comment: I guess it's because the first option is a generator comprehension?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension

Comment: I don't have 2.6 on my machine but Python 3.4 `dis` gives the same number of instructions for each method.

Comment: @IanAuld: It's not faster on 3.x (see Martijn's answer for why).

Comment: There are no set comprehensions in python 2.6, you're using a generator expression, which is slightly slower.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iteration is simply faster when using a list comprehension:

```
In [23]: from collections import deque

In [24]: %timeit deque((node[0] for node in pwnodes if node[1].get('pm')), maxlen=0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 305 µs per loop

In [25]: %timeit deque([node[0] for node in pwnodes if node[1].get('pm')], maxlen=0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 246 µs per loop
```

The `deque` is used to illustrate iteration speed; a `deque` with `maxlen` set to `0` discards all elements taken from the iterable so there are no memory allocation differences to skew the results.

That's because in *Python 2*, list comprehensions don't use a separate namespace, while a generator expression does (it has to, by necessity). That extra namespace requires a new frame on the stack, and this is expensive. The major advantage of generator expressions is their *low memory footprint*, not their speed.

In Python 3, list comprehensions have a separate namespace as well, and list comprehension and generator iteration speed is comparable. You also have set comprehensions, which are fastest still, even on Python 2.

Comment: Thanks Martijn, that explains. How do you use set comprehension on 2.6

Comment: @Anandan: you don't; you use a list comprehension or generator expression and the `set()` callable just like you did. If memory is not an issue but speed is, use the list comprehension.

Comment: A set comprehension is a new syntax added to Python 2.7 at the level of the grammar. It simply is not available in Python 2.6, and cannot be added.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is because the second one involves a generator and the first one doesn't. Generators are generally slower than the equivalent list if the equivalent list fits in memory.

```
In [4]: timeit for i in [i for i in range(1000)]: pass
10000 loops, best of 3: 47.2 µs per loop

In [5]: timeit for i in (i for i in range(1000)): pass
10000 loops, best of 3: 57.8 µs per loop
```